# Whatsapp conversations following hack

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, google-drive

So I've been incredibly stupid and allowed my whatsapp account to get hacked and am now locked out (after the hacker set up 2 step verification). I'm awaiting a response from whatsapp.

My question is, if I had a google drive backup (which i did), can the hacker view all my old messages and photos? Or do they also need my google account login details?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! How did the other person obtain your SIM number and use it during Whatsapp's registration? You should have received the SMS.